# How to parse XML with json.org.XMLTokenizer?

Tags: java, xml, org.json

So for a little while I decided to a simple xml file with the json.org library. I'm using java. Here is my XML:

```
<test attr="attr1">
  <body>value</body>
  <test2>
    <body>value</body>
  </test2>
</test>
```

I see that JsonArray looks like this:

```
["test",{"attr":"attr1"},["body","value"],["test2",["body","value"]]]
```

So I start to parse:

```
            int limit = array.length();
            List<Object>result = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for(int i = 0; i < limit; i ++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Object object = array.get(i);
                    if(object instanceof String)
                    {
                        // name of xml object
                        setName(object.toString());
                    }
                    else if(object instanceof .. ???
```

I can get the first element, which is obviously a string. But I tried parsing the other arrays using String[], Object[], List... This is basic Java so I feel I must be missing something very obvious @_@. What are those elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, and I should have guessed this, when the XMLTokenizer tokenizes this into a JSONArray object, it parses

`"test"` into a type String
`{"attr":"attr1"}` into a JSONObject and
`["body","value"]` into a JSONArray.

Also, all the code is on github, arg :P